# Uninstalling Kali Linux and restoring the GRUB of Ubuntu from a triple boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, grub2, kali

I have a system which has triple booted Windows 10, Ubuntu 16.04 and Kali Linux. I installed them in that order, so right now when I turn on the computer the GRUB from Kali Linux is what loads.

I want to uninstall Kali Linux which is the easy part. I'll just delete the partition which has Kali and it's done. But how do I restore the GRUB of Ubuntu so that I can boot Ubuntu or Windows from the bootloader menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tool called [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to easily re-install GRUB.

Boot a live session, connect to the internet, and then put this in your Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Tks!

Answer (score 0):

just login to your linux box(ubuntu 16.04 in your case) and run `sudo update-grub` . this will automatically detect the OS install on ur system.

Comment: This will not help, you would have to install Grub from Ubuntu with `sudo grub-install /dev/sdX` before you delete the Kali-partition. If you delete the Kali-partition first you can't boot to Ubuntu anymore, then the answer of @Aaron Franke will be a possibility to reinstall Grub.