# Ubuntu booting and shutting down really slowly after kali tripple boot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

My ubuntu 16.04 is booting really slowly. I had windows and ubuntu dual booted (ubuntu grub) and everything was just fine. I installed kali (and kept kali grub), and windows and kali booted just fine, but ubuntu turned really slow. I eventually retrieved ubuntu grub using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893914/uninstalling-kali-linux-and-restoring-the-grub-of-ubuntu-from-a-triple-boot) then entirely uninstalled kali using [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/930524/uninstall-kali-linux-from-triple-boot) (i opted for the virtual machine), but it's still booting really slowly, and windows is still fine. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you create new partitions for the installation of kali?  or change partitioning to make room to create the partitions?. My guess is you've changed some partitioning & thus your `/etc/fstab`has entries for a non-existing partition; which your Ubuntu tries to use/mount as it was told to. It thus waits for the device to wake up (slowing boot), eventually giving up (due timeout) and the slow boot completes. Fix this and my guess is problem solved.  (*this is only one possible cause*)

Comment: The partition change may have been a reformat of swap space, giving it a new UUID thus making the one in `/etc/fstab` incorrect...  Check you have swap on; if it's not this will be the change needed to your fstab...

Comment: @guiverc I did make some new partitions but I didn't modify an ubuntu ones, I took from my windows partition. Either way I'll look into that as soon as I get home from class and update you.

Comment: If you used UUID's to refer to partitions; taking from windoze won't have impacted, however if you used /dev/sdxy names then you may have changed things (depending on bios...).